# On Complete Separable metrizable spaces, do the compact sets generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, borel-sets

On Complete Separable metrizable spaces, do the compact sets generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra? I don't think this is true. Can anyone help me with a counterexample?

Comment: Just curious, what makes you think that it is not true?

Comment: @TheOscillator I actually do not know. But there are some Complete Separable metric function spaces that don't have the closed ball to be compact. Hence, I think there would be spaces in which open balls cannot be approximated with compact sets.

Comment: In the "positive" direction, given a Borel set $B$ and a Borel probability measure $\mu$, there is an element $K$ of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compacts (indeed, a $\mathcal K_\sigma$ set) such that $K\subset B$ and $\mu(B\setminus K)=0$.

Answer (score 7):

Any separable infinite-dimensional Banach space is a counterexample, for example $L_1$. The compact sets are meagre so they generate a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the $\sigma$-algebra of sets that are either meagre or comeagre. But the Borel $\sigma$-algebra contains the unit ball, which is neither meagre nor comeagre.

Answer (score 1):

Any separable space $X$ which is $not \ \sigma-$compact is a counterexample. To see this, let $\mathscr S$ be the $\sigma-$ring of all $\sigma-$bounded Borel sets and then define $\mathscr S^c:=\left \{ E^{c}\in \mathscr P(X): E\in \mathscr S\right \}.$ Then $\mathscr S\cup \mathscr S^c$ is the $\sigma-$algebra generated by $\mathscr S $ which contains the Borel $\sigma-$algebra generated by the compact sets, but is not all of $\mathscr B(X).$

Comment: For instance, the irrational numbers are such a space. The irrationals are completely metrisable

Comment: Do you have an argument why it is not all of $\mathscr{B}(X)$? For the irrationals, compact implies nowhere dense, which makes it easier.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: indeed maybe separability is too weak? If we make the stronger assumption of second countability, then suppose for contradiction that for each base element $U_i$, either $U_i$ or $U_i^c$ is $\sigma$-bounded. Call this $\sigma$-bounded set $V_i$. Then $X\setminus \bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N} V_i$ must be indiscrete and hence compact, so the whole space is $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb R$ with the topology $\tau$ where the closed sets are countable bounded sets, and $\mathbb R$ itself. This is separable because $\mathbb N$ is dense. The compact sets in $\tau$ are the discrete closed sets in the usual topology (not necessarily bounded). So the compact sets generate the same $\sigma$-algebra as the closed sets: countable/cocountable $\sigma$-algebra. And it's not $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks.