# Generating sigma algebra of continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Consider the space $C[0,1]$ of continuous function on unit segment with $\|f\| = \sup_{x} |f(x)|$ . We want to identify if it's true that $\mathcal{B}(C[0,1]) = \sigma(K)$, where $K$ is all compact sets of $C[0, 1]$.

I guess it's not true. But I see the only one way to do it. We need to find some $\bar{K}$: $\sigma(K) \subset \sigma(\bar{K}) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(C[0,1])$ the only candidate I've found is the set of all cylinders. But I've stuck with this way.

Any hints?

Comment: What is $B(C[0, 1])$?

Comment: @Mason borel sigma algebra of $C[0,1]$

Comment: this is essentially answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2342362/81032

Comment: Does the link above answer your question @openspace?